# Is there a Doxygen documentation plugin for Atom.io?

Tags: plugins, doxygen, atom-editor

I haven't been able to find a single package for atom.io that lets you write Doxygen-style documentation for C++ code.

I'm looking for functionality similar to https://packagecontrol.io/packages/DoxyDoxygen

Answer (score 3):

There is [Docblockr Package](https://atom.io/packages/docblockr). Docblockr claims C++ support in their README.

Installation:

```
apm install docblockr
```

I had to restart Atom, and Doxygen autocomplete began working.

Note I have already seen a few issues with PHP classes, so YMMV. However I am using [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/) (built on top of Atom), and am testing out PHP classes, so you may not run into the same issues.

Good luck!